# Get the Slim Post Request Value

Tags: php, slim

This code;

```
$email = $app->request('custom1');
print_r($email);
exit;
```

Will give;

```
Slim_Http_Request Object
(
[method:protected] => POST
[headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [host] => 192.168.56.101
        [connection] => keep-alive
        [content-length] => 26
        [cache-control] => no-cache
        [origin] => chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
        [content-type] => x-www-form-urlencoded
        [user-agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
        [postman-token] => 046f7635-49fe-5fa9-64f9-934f01b97c05
        [accept] => */*
        [accept-encoding] => gzip, deflate
        [accept-language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
        [cookie] => PHPSESSID=4effe7cedc113d0c371c64031cb2f22f; 4effe7cedc113d0c371c64031cb2f22f=DEFAULT%7C0%7C2M3TMlgUx3gTlaarYzHIdD28l8q9FTcNubt55%2BUGpAo%3D%7C7456bf61db3500c8bb7b3bc38082a470ce4a2ad3
    )

[additionalHeaders:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => content-type
        [1] => content-length
        [2] => php-auth-user
        [3] => php-auth-pw
        [4] => auth-type
        [5] => x-requested-with
    )

[cookies:protected] => Array
    (
        [PHPSESSID] => 4effe7cedc113d0c371c64031cb2f22f
        [4effe7cedc113d0c371c64031cb2f22f] => DEFAULT|0|2M3TMlgUx3gTlaarYzHIdD28l8q9FTcNubt55+UGpAo=|7456bf61db3500c8bb7b3bc38082a470ce4a2ad3
    )

[get:protected] => Array
    (
        [email] => custom1
        [listid] => 238497
        [apikey] => 928je3fb
    )

[post:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[put:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[body:protected] => custom1=mike%40example.com
[contentType:protected] => x-www-form-urlencoded
[resource:protected] => /mailchimp
[root:protected] => /index.php
)
```

How can I get `$email` to just be the value of this? So it returns "mike@example.com"?

Something like `$app->request->get('custom1');` will result in;

```
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Slim::$request in /var/www/html/index.php on line 26
```

Comment: Which version of Slim are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**:

Looking at the whole object, it seems like you've made a POST request, which has the value custom1 in the body. But, that hasn't been parsed into the request object under the POST variables.

You should be able to get the raw data like this:

```
$app->request()->getBody()
```

And parse that into your options. Seeing the content type, you'd need:

```
parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $params)
echo $params['custom1']
```

***Old answer:***

Try:

```
$app->request()->get('email');
```

You need to call `$app->request()` to get the request object, then get the parameter you want from there.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a POST Method you can try this to get variable :

```
$app->request->post() // For all
$app->request->post('custom1') // specific variable
```

I hope it'll help you